# cisco pix 501 to 5505 static(inside, outside) command doesnt work

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

Have the following commands in the pix 501, which works perfectly:

```
static (inside,outside) 68.109.247.119 192.168.1.119 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0
static (inside,outside) 68.109.247.115 192.168.1.115 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0
```

Whenever I include these in the 5505, unit accepts configuration, but now I can't ssh in from the outside, among other problems??

Comment: What version of OS is your 5505 running?  Can you show the ACL on the outside interface?  BTW, you should use [RFC 5735](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5735) outside addresses, such as 192.0.2.115

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to hit the ASA's "outside" IP via SSH.  You have to manually allow SSH to come from any interface other than the management interface if I recall correctly.  Try the commands:

```
ssh 68.109.247.119 255.255.255.255 outside
ssh 68.109.247.115 255.255.255.255 outside
```